# Find $a,b, c,d$ such that $z^{4} + 16 = (z-a)(z-b)(z-c)(z-d) $.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

My original idea was choosing $2, -2, 2i, -2i$ but that gives $$z^{4} - 16.$$ Is there a similar way to solve this?

Comment: Indeed, remembering the possible permutations of the roots, that is the solution.

Comment: @MattiP. Well, no. $2,-2,2i$ and $-2i$ are *not* the solutions as they produce $z^4-16$ instead of $z^4+16$, as mentioned in the OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substitute $z^2:=x$ to get 
$$x^2+16=(x-4i)(x+4i)$$
Thus $z_{1,2}=\pm2\sqrt{i}$ and $z_{3,4}=\pm2\sqrt{-i}$. What remains is to compute the square root of $i$ and $-i$, respectively. As $i=e^{i\frac\pi2}$ and $-i=e^{i\frac{3\pi}2}$ we get that
$$\sqrt{i}=e^{i\frac\pi4},~\sqrt{-i}=e^{i\frac{3\pi}4}$$
Now use Euler's Formula to obtain the solutions which are given by

> $$\therefore~z_1=\sqrt2(1+i),~z_2=\sqrt2(-1+i),~z_3=\sqrt2(-1-i),~z_4=\sqrt2(1-i)$$

Comment: Thanks. I have also observed that I can substitute a,b,c, and d with the roots of $z^4 + 16 = 0$  Why is that?

Comment: @S.D As a polynomial of degree four $f(z)=z^4+16$ has precisely four roots over the complex numbers $\Bbb C$ which is equivalent for $f$ to split into the product four linear polynomials over $\Bbb C$. The RHS of $z^4+16=(z-a)(z-b)(z-c)(z-d)$ *is* the product of four linear polynomials so the values of the constants coincide with the roots of the polynomial

Answer (score 1):

Sure.  There are four roots:  $2e^{\frac{\pi i}4},2e^{\frac{3\pi i}4},2e^{\frac{5\pi i}4},2e^{\frac{7\pi i}4}$.

These are gotten by taking any one root, and multiplying by $\rho,\rho^2$ and $\rho^3$ where $\rho$ is a *primitive $4$-th root of unity*, to get the other three.

You can use Euler's formula to get one (or all) of the roots: since $e^{\pi i}=-1$, we get that, for instance,  $z=2e^{\frac{\pi i}4}\implies z^4=-16$.

Answer (score 0):

We have $z^4+16=(z^2+4)^2-8z^2=(z^2+4-2\sqrt{2}z)(z^2+4+2\sqrt{2}z)=[(z-\sqrt{2})^2+2][(z+\sqrt{2})^2+2]=[(z-\sqrt{2})^2-(\sqrt{2}i)^2][(z+\sqrt{2})^2-(\sqrt{2}i)^2]=(z-2-\sqrt{2}i)(z-2+\sqrt{2}i)(z+2-\sqrt{2}i)(z+2+\sqrt{2}i)$.
$\implies (a;b;c;d)=(2+\sqrt{2}i;2-\sqrt{2}i;-2+\sqrt{2}i;-2-\sqrt{2}i)$ and permutations.